# Google Chart: Showing bars wrongly

Tags: google-visualization, bar-chart

I am currently working on [Google Bar Chart-Dual-X](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart#dual-x) and it is working nice.

**Issue:**

The bar is showing wrongly.For an example: Suppose I want to show Obtained Marks and Total Marks.But Issue is Google Chart shows Obtained Marks Bar bigger than the Total Mark(which is not true at all). You can see below pic :

[image]

[image]

As you can see in the pic that **Chap 6,7,8**  is having Obtained Mark Bar is bigger than the Total Mark Bar.

**Code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("visualization", "1.1", {packages:["bar"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawStuff);

  function drawStuff() {
    var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Subject', 'Obtained Marks', 'Total Marks'],
    <?php 
        $i=1;
        foreach($sql_get_marks_results as $sql_get_marks_result){
            echo "['".$sql_get_marks_result->meta_subject."', ".$sql_get_marks_result->obtained_marks.", ".$sql_get_marks_result->total_marks."]";
            if($i != count($sql_get_marks_results)){echo ",";}
            $i++;
        }
    ?>
    ]);

    var options = {
      width: 900,
      chart: {
        title: 'Markesheet',
        subtitle: 'distance on the left, brightness on the right'
      },
      bars: 'horizontal', // Required for Material Bar Charts.
      series: {
        0: { axis: 'obtained' }, // Bind series 0 to an axis named 'distance'.
        1: { axis: 'total' } // Bind series 1 to an axis named 'brightness'.
      },
      axes: {
        x: {
          obtained: {label: 'Obtained'}, // Bottom x-axis.
          total: {side: 'top', label: 'Total'} // Top x-axis.
        }
      }
    };

  var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('dual_x_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
};
</script>
```

Is anyone here who came across similar problem or anyone can help me out in this ?

Tell me if you want more detail about this.

Answer (score 0):

The display shown in your screen shots is correct.

The "total marks" (red) dataset follows the **bottom x-axis**.
And the "Obtained" (blue) dataset follows the **top x-axis**.

I think that the scale (inferred by your data range) of your two X-axis is quite close. And because of this it's easy to confuse them.

Dual x-axis charts are good for complementary datasets with values in very different ranges as [in the example given in the documentation](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart#dual-x).

In your case you'd be better of using a simple (single axis) bar chart to avoid that kind of confusion.